# Parsing arguments from command line for shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I am still a junior with the linux shell script and would like help with a certain script.

I would run a sample shell script such as the following from the command line that takes in a directory as an argument:

```
./script.sh /some_dir/some_exe
```

How can I parse out the "some_dir" in my shell script?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dirname command extracts the directory name from a string; so

```
THEDIR=`basename "$1"`
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bash, it should be stored in `$1`. I'm pretty sure it's the same for other shells.

Comment: Oh crap, sorry, I missed the part where you just wanted the dir of the parameter.